# Apache Ignite JIRA - Delete Issue

Tags: jira, ignite

I have created a ticket in https://issues.apache.org/jira. I am in a situation to delete this ticket. As am not having Admin access I am not able to delete this ticket.

Kindly let know how to contact the Apache Ignite JIRA admins to delete the ticket.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not the support forum for external sites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Deleting-a-ticket-from-https-issues-apache-org-jira-projects-IGNITE-issues-td22109.html

UPD

Fixed link.

Comment: Hi Mitya, the link you provided is not for deleting JIRA issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the mailing list mentioned at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/How+to+Contribute